# Flask + gevent + uwsgi - greenlet spawn cause 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, gevent

I have an issue since I added gevent to my flask project: the page spawning greenlets always timeout / bad gateway.

The part of code causing this issue is this: https://github.com/Kyria/LazyBlacksmith/blob/master/lazyblacksmith/views/ajax.py#L145-L221

Here what i've tested:

- Running my flask app with `python app.py` : works fine with or without gevent/greenlets.
- Running behind uwsgi without gevent/greenlet : works fine.
- Running behind uwsgi with gevent/greenlet : fails.

So, after searching for a while, reading uwsgi doc, i tried to add some stuff to my uwsgi conf :

```
loop = async
async = 10
greenlet = true
ugreen = true
```

After restarting my uwsgi, i didn't have to wait for error, the Bad Gateway was really quick, but with an error in the log this time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "./lazyblacksmith/views/ajax.py", line 152, in get_price_and_tax
    crest = get_crest()
  File "./lazyblacksmith/utils/crestutils.py", line 17, in get_crest
    crest()
  File "./lazyblacksmith/utils/pycrest/eve.py", line 212, in __call__
    self._data = APIObject(self.get(self._endpoint), self)
  File "./lazyblacksmith/utils/pycrest/eve.py", line 156, in get
    res = self._session.get(resource, params=prms, headers=headers)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 345, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 782, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 215, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 135, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 66, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/_socketcommon.py", line 268, in getaddrinfo
    return get_hub().resolver.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socktype, proto, flags)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/resolver_thread.py", line 64, in getaddrinfo
    return self.pool.apply(_socket.getaddrinfo, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/pool.py", line 300, in apply
    return self.spawn(func, *args, **kwds).get()
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/event.py", line 284, in get
    result = self.hub.switch()
  File "/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 592, in switch
    return greenlet.switch(self)
MemoryError
```

I also tried to add the following in my uwsgi app conf :

```
gevent = 10
gevent-monkey-patch = true
limit-as = 512
```

And i tried to increase the timeout in nginx `uwsgi_read_timeout 300`, but it didn't change anything...

My uwsgi conf is the following:

```
# lazyblacksmith.ini file
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith
home            = /home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/
callable        = app
wsgi-file       = app.py

master          = true
processes       = 10

socket          = /home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/lazyblacksmith.socket
chmod-socket    = 664
vacuum          = true
uid             = lazyblacksmith
gid             = www-data
```

My nginx conf :

```
upstream lbflask {
    server unix:/home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/env/lazyblacksmith.socket;
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name site.com; # 
    charset     utf-8;

    location /static {
        alias /home/lazyblacksmith/LazyBlacksmith/lazyblacksmith/static;
        include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  lbflask;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

I don't find anything relevant anymore :/ I think i'll end up moving my gevent stuff in tasks (with celery), but i still want to understand what is my problem...

For information:

- Debian 8
- uwsgi 2.0.7-debian
- nginx/1.6.2
- python 2.7.9
- gevent 1.1rc2
- greenlet 0.4.9

Thank you !